# Using a Keras Implementation to find optimal parameters to a function

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I was wondering if it was possible to set up a basic Keras Regression Neural Network where the inputs (x_data) are simply 4 doubles that are parameter inputs to a function which returns an array/dataframe of the same size as the measured data (y_data)? I am using a Non-Linear Optimisation at the moment but thought it might be interesting and quite cool to see if it can be solved with a neural network.

To reiterate, how to set it up so that the keras model finds optimum values for 4 parameters in order to minimize the error between an array of measured data and the output array of the function?

So for example:

```
y_data = np.array() # > 10,000 entries

x_data = [param1,param2,param3,param4]
```

But I have a function that calculates an output dataframe of equal size to the y_data and I want to find an optimum values for the 4 parameters that minimise the mean squared error between calc_votlage and y_data.

```
calc_voltage = function(param1,param2,param3,param4)
```

I want to minimize the mean squared error between calc voltage and y_data using a set-up similar to the following.

```
model = keras.Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(units = 1, activation = 'linear', input_shape=[4]))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(units = 64, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(units = 64, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(units = 64, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(units = 1, activation = 'linear'))
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer="adam")

model.fit(x_data, y_data, epochs=40, verbose=1) 

#not sure how to do this whether it should be something like this rather?

model.fit(function(param1,param2,param3,param4), y_data, epochs=40, verbose=1)
```

Comment: What error are you getting? Make sure the return value of your function is an array of shape `[num_samples, 4]`. It doesn't make sense to minimize the error between `calc_voltage`, which is your input array of shape `[num_samples, 4]` and your target array of shape `[num_samples,]`. Do you mean you want to reduce the error between the true value of the target and the predicted value of the target?

Comment: Note that the `fit` method takes two required parameters - the input array X and the true values of the target variable y in the training set. It minimizes the error between the predicted value of y and the true value of y in the training set. I'm not sure what you mean by "minimize the mean squared error between calc voltage and y_data", since one is `calc_voltage` is the input to the model and `y_data` is the target variable.

Comment: @NikhilKumar thanks for this. y_data is an array of measured voltages and the function simulates an electrical circuit based of those 4 parameters which are component values (resistances etc).  They can't be of shape [num_samples, 4] but are just 4 doubles. I need to find values for the 4 parameters so that output_votlage of the circuit function which is of shape [num_samples] matches the measured y_data  [num_samples]  from an experiment. Does this make a bit more sense?

Comment: You shouldn't be using a neural network in this case. Neural networks USE optimization algorithms to perform a certain task such as regression or classification, but aren't optimization algorithms themselves. Maybe you should be using scipy.optimize or a dedicated optimization library for your task. You could explore non-traditional optimization algorithms such as GA or PSO, too.